# SDWebimage to create folder (or group images)

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

If I just download like this, it store in default folder.

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

[manager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]
                      options:0
                     progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                         // progression tracking code
                     }
                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                        if (image)
                        {

                        }
                    }];
```

How can I group images into different folder? I saw initWithNamespace but I don't know how to use. If I use that method, how can I refer to default folder again also?